# Reverse children in contenttree umbraco

Tags: umbraco, reverse

I asked this question to on the umbraco forum but it seems unresponsive since the facelift...

I'm looking for a way to reverse the content tree of certain children in the umbraco back-office. It can be pure visual without changing the sort order.

I was looking in to adding a property to the documenttypes of a contentpage called "reverseChildren" and catch that somehow to display the children in reverse.

I did a test in the umbraco.directives.js to reverse everything but gave me some pretty erratic behavior.

Any thought on how to get this option in Umbraco as a "hack" or maybe even as a plugin?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be purely visual or can it also change the sort order?  If changing the sort order is OK then you can achieve this by opening the sort dialog and clicking on the heading of the Sort Order column.  This will reverse the sort order of the child pages.

Comment: @RobertPurcell:  Thanks for your reply. The problem is that we want to be able automaticly reverse the sorting for certain nodes (e.g. news node). 
Your proposal needs a user action everytime you add a new item.

Comment: I would question why it's necessary to perform ordering like this especially in the backend.  If you're on Umbraco 7 then you may find it better to use the ListView functionality to list all the children in a table on the parent node - then you have ordering built right in on multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the `ContentService.ContentSaved` event and then perform your ordering logic there - that way whenever a user saves a relevant node you can make sure the sort order is updated.

However, beware that with a lot of nodes this is going to have a performance hit and may not be worth your while.

Take a look here for documentation on events:

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Events/

Edit: You can use the `ContentService.Sort(IEnumerable<IContent> items, int userId = 0, bool raiseEvents = true)` method but you will still need to sort the items first before passing them in.